# Single Audiosource for multiple clips?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a couple of audio sources in a script, idea being that one is used for effects and the other for music. I am noticing that if an effect plays at the same time as another one, it actually stops the previous one from playing, probably because they are playing from the same audio source.

My question is, do I really have to instantiate a new audio source every time i want to play a new sound, just to make sure that one sound will not stop a currently playing one ? Is there a better way ?

The method that plays a sound effect(and the awake one) in my class are these :

```cs
void Awake() {
    audioSource = GetComponents<AudioSource>()[0];
    audioEffectsSource = GetComponents<AudioSource>()[1];
    audioSource.volume = PlayerPrefsManager.getMasterVolume();
    audioEffectsSource.volume = PlayerPrefsManager.getSFXMasterVolume();
}

public void playSoundEffect(AudioClip clip)
{
    if(clip != null)
    {
        audioEffectsSource.clip = clip;
        audioEffectsSource.volume = PlayerPrefsManager.getSFXMasterVolume();
        audioEffectsSource.PlayOneShot(clip);
    }
}
```

The script is attached to a musicmanager gameobject with 2 audiosources, one for music fx and one for sound tracks.

Comment: The documentation is your friend ;) https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html, so does Google : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/95274/play-vs-playoneshot

Comment: or could have pool of available audio sources (so no need to create & destroy them just for 1 sound)

Comment: That is very weird, cause I am already using PlayOneShot in my musicManager :O

Comment: Just verified with a breakpoint, indeed, playSoundEffect is called each time. I am specifically invoking an achievements sounds effect(which lasts 3-4 seconds). If I re-invoke the method by clicking a button, the previously playing achievement sound just stops.

Comment: Ooooooh, oops the line "audioEffectsSource.clip = clip;" is the issue. Oh gosh. Thanks @Hellium :D Please feel free to make this an answer and i will select it !